# Fixed navBar and sidebar overlap Semantic UI

Tags: vue.js, navbar, sidebar, semantic-ui

I'm looking to maintain fixed navbar irregardless of sidebar with it appearing under the navbar as in here with attached top/bottom:
http://codepen.io/redshift7/pen/VaKmjq

```
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
  <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical demo sidebar menu">
```

Attached segment won't work with fixed navbar where it will stretch through the page. I'd rather see the answer in vue.js.

Comment: you forgot to add reference link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make following CSS changes for this to work:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10001;
    width: 100%;
}
.pusher {
    margin-top: 36px;
}
.pushable {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Working codepen: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbKJmO)

Comment: It's not working, scrolling down will also result in sidebar scrolling through until it's out of window (isn't fixed).